# Creating a submap of guava TreeMultimap and efficient iteration of its key-value pairs

Tags: java, dictionary, guava, multimap, sortedmap

I have a `TreeMultimap<Integer, String>`, which includes duplicate keys also.

> I want to get and display the **key value pairs** which lies within a specific key
>   range, that too with **O(logN+m)** time complexity, where **N** is the total number of key value pairs and **m** is the number of key value pairs within the given range.

I am thinking of converting the TreeMultimap to a SortedMap by using its method asMap() and then creating a submap in the required range.

```
SortedMap<Integer, Collection<String>> sortedMap = mapList.getTmm().asMap();
return sortedMap.subMap(beg,end);
```

But, is using `asMap()` method efficient? How can I display each key-value pair from the object of `Collection` class with the given time complexity.

Or should I change my approach completely? Please help.

Comment: [`Multimap#asMap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html#asMap%28%29) returns **a view** of underlying multimap, so complexity of operations does not change. Is performance really a problem for you? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes. Even if space complexity is increased, it doesn't matter. But I need to implement this operation with time complexity O(logN+m). I am trying to implement zrange operation of redis server with comparable speed. So you mean asMap() complexity is O(1) ? @Xaerxess

Comment: Yes, `.asMap` is O(1).

Comment: Ok. Then, is there any way of iterating this submap efficiently? @Xaerxess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`TreeMultimap.asMap()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html#asMap--) returns a view in O(1) time that operates on the underlying structure (and so is roughly as efficient as working with the `Multimap` directly). [`NavigableMap.subMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#subMap-K-boolean-K-boolean-) similarly returns a view of *its* underlying structure. This view isn't O(1), since it has to do some searches into the larger map, but it's no worse than what you'd do to manually find the first element and then iterate.

So there is some slight overhead due to the two layers of indirection, but essentially you should expect the same performance as operating on the original data structure directly. Since `TreeMultimap` is backed by a tree common operations like get and put will be O(log n) and iteration is O(n).

All of that means that iterating over the map returned by `someTreeMultimap.asMap().subMap(...)` will be O(log n) + O(n) (so, linear), since the submap operation has to search for the first valid entry - from there it just iterates as normal until it reaches the last valid entry. You should have no trouble iterating over the `entrySet()` of the map returned from `subMap()`.